# The "system" tag

Tags: discussion, tags

What is the generic [system](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system) tag supposed to be about? There's already [control-system](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/control-system) and at least the most recent "system" questions are just of the latter kind. It would take a bit of stamina just to survey what went into the generic system tag...

Comment: It is probably the counter tag to chaos

Comment: @PlasmaHH: there's no "chaos" tag yet although it [could be a valid one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chua%27s_circuit).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is another one of those really dumb tags proliferated by people that don't know better. After a cursory glance at the usage, I would be in favor retagging and banning it.